# App-pool problems, updating credentials in stsadm

Tags: sharepoint

I opened Sharepoint 2010 Central Admin and as per normal, was prompted for my login details. As I did not know the details, I closed after a few guesses/changing the default account.

A few hours later, remembering the password, I try again but get a 503 Service Unavailable.

I check the app pools in IIS7 and see that the SharePoint Central Administration v4 app pool is off. I turn it on, close IIS7, but it turns off again. Its settings look good to me:

Enable 32-bit applications    Off
Start Automatically        True
Enabled                True

However, the application event log tells me that the account I was using to access Central Admin, and used by this app pool, has now expired (it's a local account so I did not know this will happen). This also impacts all other services such as SQL Server etc. How can I change the account of the app pool, but also change all of the other service accounts?

The credentials used for the account [name] expired on 1/9/2010 1:33:39 PM, and need to be updated. If they are not updated, the system may stop working. The account is used by the following:
Farm Account
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation User Code Service
User Profile Synchronization Service
Web Analytics Data Processing Service
Security Token Service Application
Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application]

I assume updatefarmcredentials will fix this. I tried the following:

stsadm.exe -o updatefarmcredentials -username sysaccountname -password pwvaluehere -local

This results in a "command line error". What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can also just change the current System Account password in AD or Computer Management, and mark it to not expire.

When it comes to the stsadm command, it is **userlogin** not username, unless that changed in 2010. ([Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262150.aspx))